# Reading the Excel sheeet from Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Getting error while reading the excel sheet from the local drive. I am using asp.net to read the excel sheet. My error:

The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.

```
     protected void btnup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                              
            string Extension = Path.GetExtension("Book1.xlsx");
            string FolderPath = @"D:/Book1.xlsx";             
            Import_To_Grid(FolderPath, Extension); 
    }

    private void Import_To_Grid(string FilePath, string Extension )
    {
        string conStr = "";

        switch (Extension)
        {

            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03

                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"] .ConnectionString;
                break;

            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07

                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"] .ConnectionString;
                break;

        }



        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
        {
            conn.Open();                
            DataTable sheetsName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[]       { null, null, null, "Table" });                
            string firstSheetName = sheetsName.Rows[0][2].ToString();                 
            string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", firstSheetName);
            OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conStr);
            DataSet set = new DataSet();
            ada.Fill(set);

        }
        }
```

I am getting error at conn.Open().

Comment: show the code you are using!!!!! also remember, if there are multiple people accessing that same file, you will have this problem.

Comment: No one using the file.

Answer (score 0):

This error may happen because you are opening that excel file by using MS Office or another process is opening your excel file.

Comment: Yes Phong vo, i am using the ...... "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}"

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution for my question. Actually i did some thing wrong in connection string in connection string at source i not given the path, that is the reason it is throwing error.